# Sort array of object using underscore js

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, underscore.js

I have array of object as follows:

```
profData=[{"Details":{"CODE":"PAT4PAS","DESCRIPTION":"PASTIE 4N20 12 X 175G","LOCATION":"FREEZER","UNITS":"BOX","WAREHOUSE":"00","AVAILABLE":"15.0000","ON_HAND":"15.0000","BRAND":"4N20","PRICE1":"18.80","TAX_CODE1":"1","PROD_CLASS":"FROZ"}},{"Details":{"CODE":"PAT4PAS","DESCRIPTION":"PASTIE 4N20 12 X 175G","LOCATION":"FREEZER","UNITS":"BOX","WAREHOUSE":"00","AVAILABLE":"15.0000","ON_HAND":"15.0000","BRAND":"4N20","PRICE1":"18.80","TAX_CODE1":"1","PROD_CLASS":"FROZ"}},{"Details":{"CODE":"OMKM","DESCRIPTION":"SAUCE KETCHUP MANIS 620ML [6]","LOCATION":"DRY","UNITS":"EACH","WAREHOUSE":"00","AVAILABLE":"187.0000","ON_HAND":"189.0000","BRAND":"ABC","PRICE1":"3.40","TAX_CODE1":"-1","PROD_CLASS":"DRY"}},{"Details":{"CODE":"BAXSAL","DESCRIPTION":"SALSA MEXICAN 2LTR [6]","LOCATION":"DRY","UNITS":"EACH","WAREHOUSE":"00","AVAILABLE":"439.0000","ON_HAND":"445.0000","BRAND":"AGE","PRICE1":"9.20","TAX_CODE1":"-1","PROD_CLASS":"DRY"}},{"Details":{"CODE":"BAXSEMI","DESCRIPTION":"TOMATO SEMI DRIED 2KG [4]","LOCATION":"REFRIDGERATOR","UNITS":"EACH","WAREHOUSE":"00","AVAILABLE":"55.0000","ON_HAND":"59.0000","BRAND":"AGE","PRICE1":"21.10","TAX_CODE1":"-1","PROD_CLASS":"CHILL"}},{"Details":{"CODE":"BAXSUN","DESCRIPTION":"TOMATO SUN DRIED 2KG [4]","LOCATION":"REFRIDGERATOR","UNITS":"EACH","WAREHOUSE":"00","AVAILABLE":"39.0000","ON_HAND":"39.0000","BRAND":"AGE","PRICE1":"15.20","TAX_CODE1":"-1","PROD_CLASS":"CHILL"}},{"Details":{"CODE":"AMFBAM","DESCRIPTION":"FLOUR - AM SUP BAKERS 12.5KG","LOCATION":"REFRIDGERATOR","UNITS":"BAG","WAREHOUSE":"00","AVAILABLE":"259.0000","ON_HAND":"339.0000","BRAND":"ALLIE","PRICE1":"13.70","TAX_CODE1":"-1","PROD_CLASS":"CHILL"}},{"Details":{"CODE":"ALPKKC","DESCRIPTION":"KRANSKY - CHEESE 2.5KG [6]","LOCATION":"REFRIDGERATOR","UNITS":"EACH","WAREHOUSE":"00","AVAILABLE":"27.0000","ON_HAND":"27.0000","BRAND":"ALP","PRICE1":"19.30","TAX_CODE1":"-1","PROD_CLASS":"CHILL"}},{"Details":{"CODE":"ABTDP","DESCRIPTION":"TOOTHPICK - DOUBLE POINT 1000","LOCATION":"DRY","UNITS":"EACH","WAREHOUSE":"00","AVAILABLE":"12.0000","ON_HAND":"12.0000","BRAND":"ALPEN","PRICE1":"1.60","TAX_CODE1":"1","PROD_CLASS":"DRY"}}]
```

I want sorted it with `PROD_CLASS`,

I have tried it with underscore js but didnt get solution.

```
var fullySorted = _.sortBy(profData, 'PROD_CLASS');
```

but it not sorting with `PROD_CLASS`.

can anyone help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `PROD_CLASS` is not direct property of array element this will not work.

```
_.sortBy(profData, obj => obj.Details.PROD_CLASS);
```

This is same as

```
_.sortBy(arr, function(obj) {
    return obj.Details.PROD_CLASS;
});
```

```js
var profData = [{
    "Details": {
        "CODE": "PAT4PAS",
        "DESCRIPTION": "PASTIE 4N20 12 X 175G",
        "LOCATION": "FREEZER",
        "UNITS": "BOX",
        "WAREHOUSE": "00",
        "AVAILABLE": "15.0000",
        "ON_HAND": "15.0000",
        "BRAND": "4N20",
        "PRICE1": "18.80",
        "TAX_CODE1": "1",
        "PROD_CLASS": "FROZ"
    }
}, {
    "Details": {
        "CODE": "PAT4PAS",
        "DESCRIPTION": "PASTIE 4N20 12 X 175G",
        "LOCATION": "FREEZER",
        "UNITS": "BOX",
        "WAREHOUSE": "00",
        "AVAILABLE": "15.0000",
        "ON_HAND": "15.0000",
        "BRAND": "4N20",
        "PRICE1": "18.80",
        "TAX_CODE1": "1",
        "PROD_CLASS": "FROZ"
    }
}, {
    "Details": {
        "CODE": "OMKM",
        "DESCRIPTION": "SAUCE KETCHUP MANIS 620ML [6]",
        "LOCATION": "DRY",
        "UNITS": "EACH",
        "WAREHOUSE": "00",
        "AVAILABLE": "187.0000",
        "ON_HAND": "189.0000",
        "BRAND": "ABC",
        "PRICE1": "3.40",
        "TAX_CODE1": "-1",
        "PROD_CLASS": "DRY"
    }
}, {
    "Details": {
        "CODE": "BAXSAL",
        "DESCRIPTION": "SALSA MEXICAN 2LTR [6]",
        "LOCATION": "DRY",
        "UNITS": "EACH",
        "WAREHOUSE": "00",
        "AVAILABLE": "439.0000",
        "ON_HAND": "445.0000",
        "BRAND": "AGE",
        "PRICE1": "9.20",
        "TAX_CODE1": "-1",
        "PROD_CLASS": "DRY"
    }
}, {
    "Details": {
        "CODE": "BAXSEMI",
        "DESCRIPTION": "TOMATO SEMI DRIED 2KG [4]",
        "LOCATION": "REFRIDGERATOR",
        "UNITS": "EACH",
        "WAREHOUSE": "00",
        "AVAILABLE": "55.0000",
        "ON_HAND": "59.0000",
        "BRAND": "AGE",
        "PRICE1": "21.10",
        "TAX_CODE1": "-1",
        "PROD_CLASS": "CHILL"
    }
}, {
    "Details": {
        "CODE": "BAXSUN",
        "DESCRIPTION": "TOMATO SUN DRIED 2KG [4]",
        "LOCATION": "REFRIDGERATOR",
        "UNITS": "EACH",
        "WAREHOUSE": "00",
        "AVAILABLE": "39.0000",
        "ON_HAND": "39.0000",
        "BRAND": "AGE",
        "PRICE1": "15.20",
        "TAX_CODE1": "-1",
        "PROD_CLASS": "CHILL"
    }
}, {
    "Details": {
        "CODE": "AMFBAM",
        "DESCRIPTION": "FLOUR - AM SUP BAKERS 12.5KG",
        "LOCATION": "REFRIDGERATOR",
        "UNITS": "BAG",
        "WAREHOUSE": "00",
        "AVAILABLE": "259.0000",
        "ON_HAND": "339.0000",
        "BRAND": "ALLIE",
        "PRICE1": "13.70",
        "TAX_CODE1": "-1",
        "PROD_CLASS": "CHILL"
    }
}, {
    "Details": {
        "CODE": "ALPKKC",
        "DESCRIPTION": "KRANSKY - CHEESE 2.5KG [6]",
        "LOCATION": "REFRIDGERATOR",
        "UNITS": "EACH",
        "WAREHOUSE": "00",
        "AVAILABLE": "27.0000",
        "ON_HAND": "27.0000",
        "BRAND": "ALP",
        "PRICE1": "19.30",
        "TAX_CODE1": "-1",
        "PROD_CLASS": "CHILL"
    }
}, {
    "Details": {
        "CODE": "ABTDP",
        "DESCRIPTION": "TOOTHPICK - DOUBLE POINT 1000",
        "LOCATION": "DRY",
        "UNITS": "EACH",
        "WAREHOUSE": "00",
        "AVAILABLE": "12.0000",
        "ON_HAND": "12.0000",
        "BRAND": "ALPEN",
        "PRICE1": "1.60",
        "TAX_CODE1": "1",
        "PROD_CLASS": "DRY"
    }
}];

var fullySorted = _.sortBy(profData, obj => obj.Details.PROD_CLASS);
console.log(fullySorted);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```

**Using Lodash:**

```
_.sortBy(profData, 'Details.PROD_CLASS');
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. what if I have to sort it with brand as well as like follows:
in list is sorted by "product class" and then "Brand"

Comment: @VRK Using Lodash `_.chain(profData).sortBy('Details.PROD_CLASS').sortBy('BRAND').value();`.